# For any two different vectors of the same length, the Householder transformation with $v = x - y$ gives $Hx = y$ and $Hy = x$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on this problem.

> Show that for any two different vectors of the same length, $||x|| = ||y||$, the Householder transformation with $v = x - y$ gives $Hx = y$ and $Hy = x$.

(Gilbert Strang, *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* 4e, 7.3.5)

Note that Strang defines $H = I - 2\frac{vv^T}{||v||^2}$, allowing for $v$ of any length.

If we can show $Hx = y$, we get $Hy = x$ for free since the Householder transformation is a reflection.

I expected the solution to take a similar form to this proof given for $Hx = -\sigma z$ in the text:

> Where $z$ is the column vector $(1, 0, ... , 0)$, $\sigma=||x||$, and $v = x + \sigma z$,
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> Hx & = x - \frac{2vv^Tx}{||{v}||^2} = x - (x+ \sigma z)\frac{2(x+ \sigma z)^T x}{(x+ \sigma z)^T(x+ \sigma z)} \\
>  & = x - (x+ \sigma z) \qquad (\text{because } x^Tx = \sigma^2)\\
>  & = -\sigma z
> \end{align}
> $$

But I don't understand how to justify canceling out the big fraction in the first line like this. Applying the distributive property gets you the $x^T x$, but I can't tell what Strang does to get rid of the $\sigma z^T x$ term.

The solution given says,

> $$
> Hx = x - (x-y)\frac{(x-y)^T x}{(x-y)^T(x-y)} = x - (x-y) = y.
> $$

Again, how do we know $\frac{(x-y)^T x}{(x-y)^T(x-y)} =1$? And where did the 2 go?

I'd appreciate a more detailed expansion of either the $Hx = -\sigma z$ proof or the solution to the practice problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the proof of $Hx=-\sigma z$, expand both the numerator and denominator and use $x^Tx=\sigma^2$, just as it says on the second line. Remember, too, that $x^Tz=z^Tx$. Similarly, expand both the numerator and denominator of $${2(x-y)^Tx\over(x-y)^T(x-y)}$$ and use the hypothesis that $x^Tx=y^Ty$. The omission of the factor of $2$ in the solution is likely a typo.

Comment: This expansion is precisely the thing I don't understand. Multiplying out what you've written, I get $2(x^Tx - x^Ty) / (x^Tx-2x^Ty + y^Ty)$. How do I show that this equals one?

Comment: Aha! And then since $x^Tx = y^Ty$, you factor out a two. Thanks.